# Custom modules not read by Python, generating ImportError

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python pipeline through Mac OS Terminal. I am using Python 2.7.15 because newer versions of Python gave me error messages with this file. I keep getting the following error message:

```
$ python ../../../scripts/gemmaPipeline.py ../../../data/all.fixGL.Q10.ap.bi.MAF5.vcf.gz outfile Results
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "../../../scripts/gemmaPipeline.py", line 5, in 
>       `import utils, vcf, genomes100, gemma ImportError`: No module named `genomes100`

The modules listed in the import command are present under the "scripts" folder in a subfolder "modules". For each of the four modules, I have a .py and .pyc file in this subfolder. I cannot get Python to find this path.

I have tried running the same script within a virtualenv but to no avail. I even tried moving the "modules" subfolder to the Python "site-packages" folder in hopes that it would work but failed.

Finally, I tried including an **init**.py file (blank) in the "script" folder, but that didn't work either.

I am an utter novice and am pretty much learning as I go.Please help.

Comment: Have you set your `$PYTHONPATH` to point to the directory with the genomes100 module in it?

Comment: I am not completely sure how this is done. Would I need to edit the .bash_profile file (OSX) to specify the PYTHONPATH? or should the import the path into the python script (using sys.path.append ("/Users/Application/modules/")?

Comment: either approach will work

Comment: Unless you're importing from genomes100 frequently, I'd suggesting using `sys.path.append`.  Just be sure to set the path before trying to import from your custom module.